# use image as radio button's option

Tags: lightning-aura-components, radiogroup

```
 <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'Sales', 'value': 'option1'},
    {'label': 'Force', 'value': 'option2'}
    ]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" default="option1"/>
```

```
    <lightning:radioGroup name="radioGroup"
                          label="Radio Group"
                          options="{! v.options }"
                          value="{! v.value }"
                          type="radio"/>
```

I am using `lightning:radioGroup`.

I want to use image(png or gif) as options, but I can't find such a case.

[image: radioimage]

I mean that I want to set image instead of 'Sales' and 'Force' in above picture.

How do I this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lightning:radioGroup` doesn't support `png/gif` type for Option attribute `label/value` properties other than `string` type. [radio button group Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/example) but for your Use case you can check out [lightning:carousel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:carousel/example) with customization [image]

Comment: Thank you for intoducing carousel .